# Contact us form content change in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: forms, contact-us

I am new to Magento and I am trying to add some content in `contact-us` form.

I changed some text in the following file and cleared the cache, but its don't reflecting.

Please help me.

```
app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/contacts/form.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Some most common changes made to the Magento contact page and form in this link. **Note** to `clear your Magento and browser cache` before previewing the results of the changes.

And most useful link check

**https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-edit-contact-us-page.html**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Note to clear your Magento and browser cache and try